# Printing output into a table format using Java swing

Tags: swing, tabular

How can I show my output in a tabular format? My data structure is a hash map. Using swing, or  I can print the table into a file instead.

Comment: Please include some code in your Q ...

Answer (score 0):

Whether plain text file or `JTable`, you'll need to [iterate over the map](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/maps/map_iteration.html).